# Getting exact symbol using HTMLParser

Tags: python, html-parser

`HTMLParser.unescape` behaves like this:

```
>>> import HTMLParser
>>> h= HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
>>> h.unescape('alpha &lt; &beta;')
u'alpha < \u03b2'
```

What should I do to get the exact `beta` symbol instead of `\u03b2`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\u03b2` **is** "the exact `beta` symbol".

You must learn to distinguish between a thing and a representation of that thing.

Your string consists of lowercase letter a, lowercase letter l, lowercase letter p, lowercase letter h, lowercase letter a, space, left angle bracket, space, and beta.

The `u'...'` sequence is a representation of a string. It shows you **one possible** sequence of characters that you could *type into a Python source file* in order to express the concept of that string. `u'foo'` is the string `foo`. So is `u'\x66\x6f\x6f'`. So is `u'\u0066\u006f\u006f'`. When you ask Python to display the representation of any of those, it will display `u'foo'`, because that's what Python considers to be the simplest representation of that string.

When you **print** `u'\u0066\u006f\u006f'`, you will see `foo`, with no `u` prefix and no quotes - because now you are asking for a *text* representation, instead of a *source code* representation. You can do the same with the string you have in your program: `print h.unescape('alpha &lt; &beta;')`, and **if** your terminal is currently capable of displaying `β`, you should see `alpha < β`. If it doesn't, you'll typically get a UnicodeEncodeError, as Python attempts to send a *byte* representation of the string to your terminal (using some kind of string encoding to turn the characters into bytes), and the encoding isn't designed to handle `β`. For **that** problem, please see [Python, Unicode, and the Windows console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419/python-unicode-and-the-windows-console)